# iOSでBluetoothのMACアドレスを知りたいのですが（プログラムで）

Tags: ios, bluetooth

iOSでプログラムからbluetoothのMACアドレスを知りたいのですがどうすればいいのですか？WebでしらべるとiOS7以降ではできないらしいですが。設定画面のMACアドレスを読みとるだけでもいいのですが。

Comment: 単なる興味なのですが、MACアドレスを何に使用されるのでしょうか？

Comment: 近くのbluetoothのMACアドレスを一覧表示するアプリを作ったのですが、これとログイン情報をリンクさせていろいろ^^;したいのです

Comment: なるほど。MACアドレスを用いて自動ログイン的なのを想定していますか？

Comment: そんな感じです。そして近くの人を勝手に発見、情報のぞきみ＋メッセ−ジ送信とかです

Comment: そのような用途で、名寄せや個人特定が可能なMACアドレスを使用する必要はありますか？

Comment: リストアップされたMACアドレスを人のログイン名にコンバートしたいのです。もしMACアドレスとLOGIN名がリンクされればできます